# "Muppet" in American English

Tags: nouns, american-english, slang, transatlantic-differences

I see an event is being organised in Washington, DC, called the [Million Muppet March](http://millionmuppetmarch.com/). In British English, at least, [muppet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/muppet) has no very positive connotations:-

> muppet  (ˈmʌpɪt)     — n     slang  a stupid person

Is that also the case in American slang?

Comment: [Muppets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muppet) are Jim Henson's puppets.  The word is strongly associated with Sesame Street characters.

Comment: Even in the UK we know what Muppets are. In the US, is the word "muppet" (no capital) used as a [normally] friendly way to refer to stupid people?

Comment: "Is that also the case in American slang?" This is a General Reference question. You can check any contemporary dictionary for the right answer.

Comment: I guess the answer is actually No, because I can't find a pertinent reference in an American online dictionary. Which may be why the question was asked. What is the right answer and where is the General Reference to be found?

Comment: What's going on with the second sentence in your question? :o

Comment: @AndrewLeach In the US, *muppets* = *Muppets*. Out of context, the question would be GR. In the context of the March, we have answers below.

Comment: As a Brit, I would say that the dictionary is wrong. 'Muppet' is something you say when taking the p*ss out of a friend who has just done something stupid but hilarious. It is not an insult.

Comment: "Million Muppet March" is probably in part a snowclone of the [Million Man March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Million_Man_March)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In American English, 'muppet', capitalized or not, has no meaning other than being characterized by the Jim Henson branded characters. The idea of it being a 'stupid person' is unknown. Some of the Muppet characters are slow, others are bright, others have other personality traits.

To call someone in the US a muppet would only make one wonder, 'Which one? Miss Piggy? Fozzy? Beaker?'

Comment: The song "[Man or Muppet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8EURqoKLY8)" implies being a *Muppet* is akin to being immature or not "grown-up", though a *Muppet* unquestionably refers to the Jim Henson creation. There are no additional connotations in American English (outside of the recent film) that I'm aware of. Aside from *Muppet* aficionados, it's unlikely one would refer to an immature person as a *Muppet*.

Answer (score 3):

They are genuinely going to march with Muppets (capitalised and trademarked) to protest the cutting of funding for PBS (who hosts Sesame Street)

[WSBT](http://articles.wsbt.com/2012-10-14/puppet-protest_34453644)

> A grassroots protest to save PBS funding, dubbed the Million Muppet March, is scheduled for Saturday, Nov. 3 -- three days before the presidential election -- at the National Mall.
>   Mitt Romney's threats during the first presidential debate to cut federal subsidies for PBS galvanized support for the "Sesame Street" network -- including Michael Bellavia and Chris Mecham.

[Muppet (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Muppet)

> Trademark (U.S.) Sept. 26, 1972, claiming use from 1971, but in print from Sept. 1970. Name coined by creator Jim Henson (1936-1990), who said, despite the resemblance to marionette and puppet (they have qualities of both), it has no etymology; he just liked the sound.

As for the question about the slang, I would think calling someone a muppet will be negative in any language, denoting a person with someone else's hand up inside making them do their bidding

[muppet - Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=muppet):

> A person who is ignorant and generally has no idea about anything.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question about the uncapitalised word *muppet*, which has the UK slang meaning Brian Hooper mentioned.

Comment: Definition of *muppet* is GR. The post can get closed.

Answer (score 2):

As a dual citizen of both countries I can say beyond a doubt there is no American equivalent of the British slang word muppet. Same goes for plonker, wally, jesse and many many more. The British are very creative.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of the British usage of "muppet", see the film *Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels*, in which the character "Hatchet" Harry Lonsdale (played by P.H. Moriarty) remarks, "I don't care who you use as long as they're not complete muppets".

"Moppet" is an alternative spelling for "Poppet" (see the Wikipedia article on Poppet) and has nothing to do with "muppet". If a chap calls his girlfriend a poppet he will probably be in her good books; if he calls her a muppet he will regret it.

Answer (score 0):

Reuters [reports](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/10/13/million-muppet-march-romney-pbs-big-bird_n_1962831.html):
*'Million Muppet March' Planned To Defend PBS After Romney Big Bird Comments*

> Plans to save Big Bird, the fuzzy yellow character on U.S. public television's "Sesame Street," from possible extinction are taking shape in the form of a puppet-based protest next month dubbed the "Million Muppet March."

The context explains the use of the term Muppet here.

[All about The Muppets & Sesame Street](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/What_is_a_Muppet?)

> The term Muppet was invented by Jim Henson at the beginning of his career to describe his puppet act. It is sometimes claimed, and refuted, that Henson created the term as a combination of the words marionette and puppet. Henson used the Muppet name to define the characters in his productions, and to distinguish his act from those of other puppeteers.

Comment: Again, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach What according to you ***is*** the question, please? OP's question is properly and adequately covered here. Get some clarifications from OP, or tell us your doubts.

Comment: I would say this answer is a duplicate of mine with different links.

Comment: @mplungjan and different pieces of information, different purpose. :) Incidentally, we were both working on the answers at the same time.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The question specifically referenced the "Million Muppet March". Follow the link in the question and it takes you to a page which is clearly referring to the Sesame Street characters, and not to the UK slang term. According to Collins English Dictionary, that slang term derives from the Sesame Street character. Oh, click on the link for the definition in the OP and it references Collins, and quotes it as saying that it comes from the SS character.

Comment: @Jay The Collins entry does not say whether the definition is relevant in the US. It's not clear whether "World English" means "non-American" or "non-British".

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's true. Is that what you see as the unanswered question? As an American I have never heard the word "muppet" used as an insult or in anything other than the literal sense of referring to a puppet. I doubt this is a common usage in America. Whether it is common elsewhere I don't know. It's possible the Collins folks just found a couple of stray uses, or maybe it's common in some parts of the world. I don't know what their criteria are for adding a word to their dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S., the term "muppet" is also used in the financial product sales industry (read: stock brokers) to refer to a "mark"; a ignorant individual who can be easily exploited.